# NodeJS, WebStorm and Jasmine: ReferenceError: describe is not defined when debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, webstorm

I'm trying to debug some Jasmine tests that I have written using WebStorm 2016.1.2.

My test code looks like this:

```
var should = require("should");
var myLib = require("../my-lib");

describe("Scenario", () => {
    it("works as expected", () => {
        myLib.do().should.not.throw()
    });
});
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
│
├───node_modules
│   ├───.bin
│   ├───aws-sdk
│   │   └───<snip>
│   ├───jasmine
│   │   └───<snip>
│   ├───jasmine-core
│   │   └───<snip>
│   ├───karma
│   │   └───<snip>
│   ├───karma-jasmine
│   │   └───<snip>
│   ├───should
│   │   └───<snip>
│   └───sinon
│       └───<snip>
├───spec
│   ├───support
│   │   └───jasmine.json
│   └───my-lib.spec.js
└───my-lib.js
```

And my NodeJS settings in WebStorm look like this:

[image: WebStorm Javascript Library Settings]

To debug I'm just hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> and choosing the `my-lib.spec.js` file to run. I Then get the following stack trace:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.1.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=22714 my-lib.spec.js
Debugger listening on port 22714
c:\Users\<me>\WebstormProjects\my-lib\spec\my-lib.spec.js:4
describe("Scenario", () => {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\<me>\WebstormProjects\my-lib\spec\<my-lib>.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:442:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If anyone knows how to make WebStorm recognise that Jasmine is installed globally that'd be great.

**EDIT:** I've set up a Karma run configuration as suggested by lena with the following configuration:
[image: Karma configuration]

When I hit F5 to run this, a Chrome browser pops up and is blank (I have the JetBrains plugin for Chrome installed)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using mocha  along with should?

Comment: Can you just require('jasmine'); in the test file?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out ?

Comment: From the answer from @lena, I started using Karma to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Node.js run configuration to run your tests - and Node knows nothing about your test framework. You should be using a test runner (karma, for example - as you have karma installed). Try using karma run configuration. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+JavaScript+tests+with+Karma.

BTW, if you like using Should with karma, try [karma-should](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-should)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `jasmine-node` module.

It depends on the command send to the js file when you press F5.  It needs to be `jasmine-node <test files>` not `node <test files>`.

Try doing that in the console/terminal and see if it works.  It could be web storm sending the wrong command.

If you haven't got jasmine node installed you can do

`npm install jasmine-node -g`

Comment: `jasmine-node` hasn't been updated in a long time and doesn't support the latest version of Jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

use `mocha test.js`, not `node test.js`

Answer (score 0):

To find the answer to this, I ran DiffMerge on my project root and a new Angular CLI project created in Webstorm that properly detected jasmine types.

What I found is that the `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files *from my project* defined `typeRoots` and `types`, whereas the other project did not.

[image]

The behavior of the [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) option is:

> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

`Types` behaves a similar way.

Typescript documentation goes on to say:

> By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible.

So, for my project, this behavior is good enough for me. Deleting `typeRoots` and `types` from both my `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files solved this *immediately*.

Answer (score -2):

In your main folder, there is a 'package.json' file.
Open that and you will see something like this:

```
{
  "name": "prep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js", //This can be different
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node .",
    "posttest": "npm run lint && nsp check"
  }, ....
```

Then add the following after "start": "node .", => "test": "jasmine". 
It should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "prep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "jasmine",
    "posttest": "npm run lint && nsp check"
  },....
```

Then run 'npm test' in the terminal